# how to track only the changed values in the repeater asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a editable nested repeater containing the data.I use it for showing the data and also for saving the data which is updated by the user.
I want to detect particular cell/row for which the data has been modified by the user so that I can update only that particular row in the database instead of saving all the data again. 
Is there a way to work this out.Which would be the best technique to use ,Javascript or server side code ?

```
Resource country etc |            Week1   Week2   Week3   | Total
ABC            XYZ                  10      15      20         45
```

This is the repeater structure.
Middle one (Weeks showing hours worked by resource which is editable) is the nested repeater.
Values can only be changed in the nested repeater.
I maintain unique ID's for each resource in the hidden field.

Can you suggest me some ways to achieve this functionlity ?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally handled by your ORM, but you can implement it yourself if you like.  The idea is called 'change tracking', and basically what's commonly done is to retrieve the record from the database, then compare known retrieve values to the new values before saving it again.

Depending on your concurrency strategy, you also might use a hash of the original values that were sent to the client, placed in a hidden field perhaps, which you can then check original vs. currently in the database in order to not accidentally overwrite someone else's changes.